# How to cast AnsiString to char?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++builder-xe8

What I'm troubling about is conversion. I'm using C++ Rad Studio XE8 (don't ask why cause I had to).

I have variables

```
AnsiString a = "D8";
char sz;
```

I want `sz` to look like this

```
char sz = 0xD8;
```

How do I cast the `AnsiString` `a` to `char` so that `sz` will end up equaling `0xD8`?

I have tried `memcpy`, `strcpy`, etc. yet couldn't find solutions.

Comment: `0xD8` is not a valid char value (char ranges from `-128` to `+127`)

Comment: hmm then we should use unsigned char then ?

Comment: One option would be `unsigned char sz = strtol( a.c_str(), NULL, 16 );`

Comment: What is `AnsiString`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @KeithThompson: [`AnsiString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AnsiString) is a native string class in C++Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
unsigned char sz = strtol( a.c_str(), NULL, 16 );
```

Note that `unsigned char` is preferable because plain char is signed, and `0xD8` is out of range of plain char.

Comment: Yep ur right. :) i never thought about it. i knew that int is -32xxx to + 32xxx
 and we are not working with - so i figured out writing unsigned int is better option. But couldnt figure it on chars ^^

Comment: @RepiatX you'll find that int is 32-bit in C++Builder

Comment: Yes , it performs out-of-range conversion (which is OK but it's generally better to avoid that if there's an easy alternative)

Comment: what you meant by 32 bit? can u explain(or just give me sites to resource) 2-  Why we write 16 as a paramater on strtol? (because 16base?)

Comment: "int is 32-bit" means the range of `int` is `-2147483648` to `+2147483647`, not 32768 etc. as you seemed to be suggesting.  The `16` in strtol does indeed mean base 16. You could look up its documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A more "C++Builder-ish" way of doing this is

```
unsigned char sz = StrToInt("0x" + a);
```

Though it will make an unnecessary memory allocation.

Comment: thx for replyn thou i get my answer. Yet i got too deep on c functions and forgot about "StrToInt" lol :) thx again

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
unsigned char sz = (unsigned char) std::stoul(a, 0, 16);
```